# Qt Creator and build configuration directories on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qt-creator

On Windows Qt Creator creates a different directory for Debug and Release, but on Ubuntu it creates a single directory and places both builds in it.

This is a problem for me because, if I change from Debug to Release (or the opposite) I have to execute 'Clean' or 'Rebuild', executing just 'Build' does nothing because make thinks all files are up to date - but they are up to date for the other build configuration.

Can I make Qt Creator use different directories for Debug and Release on Linux as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Qt Creator version 2.2.82 (at least, other versions probably allow this but I only have that right now), you can set each of your build configurations to build in a different directory.

Got to the "Projects" page, select the build configuration you want, and check the "Shadow build" option and input the path you want for the build directory.